Should my webserver listen to public IP?
My nginx configuration is:
server {
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     ...
     listen 185.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl; #server public ip
}

Recently I found that anyone can configure a domain like evildomainxyz.com with my IP address and my server responds with my website.

Is it a bad practice or  potential threat to listen to public IP?

What are the caveats of not listening to the public IP but only port and server name?

Is it better to create another server{} block with something like server_name _; and redirect to main domain (although it doesn't seem to change anything).



All web servers want to  show something when clients make a request with the bare IP-address and/or when the client request uses an unknown domain name. That something is  the webservers default website , the default nginx server and associated default TLS certificate (when the clients make a https request). https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

You should create an additional server  and designate that as the default_server to handle those requests when you don’t want that one of your “real” websites gets used as the default. Your default server can redirect to your main site, show a blank page or custom html error message, as you prefer.


Is it a bad practice and there is a potential threat and i shouldn't listen to public ip, only port and server name? What are the caveats?

You have to listen to the public IP. TCP connections work on IP, not domain names.
What you should do if this problem bothers you is to create an additional server block, places first in your config, that shows a blank page or similar. Unknown hostnames gets served the first matching server { ... }-stanza, and it may be an good idea to hand out empty pages to such requests.

Either put it first, or as commented put it in any order with default_server on the listen directive
